# Зачем проверять наличие нескольких значений в getResources для одного пути класса?

Tags: java, classloader, slf4j

Скажите, разве бывает возможно, что через `ClassLoader.getResources("org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class");` можно получит несколько значений одного пути. Насколько я понимаю это физически невозможно на уровне файловой системы? Или я в чем-то ошибаюсь (объясните пожалуйста как и при каких условиях это возможно)?

Такое получение делают в `slf4j` [ссылка на гитхаб](https://github.com/qos-ch/slf4j/blob/master/slf4j-api/src/main/java/org/slf4j/LoggerFactory.java#L290-L313)

Answer (score 0):

Да, это возможно.Т.к. в classpath'е могут присутствовать несколько версий данного класса, например, в разных jar'никах.